# WSS 3.0 Write to New Column in User Information List

Tags: wss-3.0, forms-authentication, user

I am working on a site that is using FBA in WSS 3.0. This is an external facing site, so in the FBA User Management page (UsersDisp.aspx) I would like to add a column that displays the user's company name. In order to do this, I added a column named "Company" into the User Information List in order to accommodate this extra piece of information. However, where I'm encountering an issue is getting the information from my newly added input field on the "New FBA User" setup page (UserNew.aspx) into the User Information List.

I created the new input element by copying a block of code in UserNew.aspx that is used to create a different input element and changed the Title, LabelText, and ID attributes to reflect the data that will go into the field. For the ID, I stuck to the naming convention that appeared to be used by only changing the portion that distinguishes that element from another (e.g. I copied a code block having an element with ID myFldUsrNm and I changed it to myFldCmpny). Whenever I set up a new FBA user and press the "OK" button at the bottom of the page, the user is created and all information gets transferred to the User Information List EXCEPT for the data in my new field. I'm sure there is some script or page that needs to be adjusted in order to include the new field, I'm just not sure what it is or where it lives.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I'd be happy to post whatever code snippets might be useful in assisting with this issue. Thanks in advance!

-Tom

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange and thank you for joining! You can read about the community guidelines in the FAQ: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq and you can learn more about how the site works in the About section: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/about These resources will help you familiarize yourself with the site.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule is not recomanded to change in any way the schema of the User Information List. I understand that you are running WSS v3, therefore no User profiles available, but I'm thinking that you considered using FBA authentication, which relies on the ASP.NET provider model. I'm assuming that you do not want to rely on AD either, so no Windows Authentication, but you could still rely on ADAM (perfect for integrating with SharePoint 2007/2010, and a lot of flexibility in adding as many attributes as you'd like).

To authenticate, you could  the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider - follow this for complete walkthrough to get it configured - [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/scaravajal/sharepoint-2007-and-adam) or http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1161

Additionally, you could rather consider SQLMembershipProvider which again would give full flexibility in configuring as many attributes possible - see here http://blogs.technet.com/b/mhatch/archive/2007/03/10/sharepoint-2007-forms-authentication-and-aspnetsqlmembershipprovider.aspx

Both will allow you to stay away from User Information List -and out of trouble for later migrations - which is not supported if you change it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, I know little about SharePoint/.net development and frankly, I don't even know where I would get started on figuring out whether the SP site I'm referencing uses ADAM or some other authentication method. In thinking about this more, I feel like my initial question boils down to this: Is there a function or page I can edit that will insert my value into the "Company" field that I created in the User Information List or will I have to rely on something like SPServices (http://spservices.codeplex.com) to set my value? (More in 2nd comment.....)

Comment: I'm comfortable with jQuery and think I could get it done with SPServices, so as long as SharePoint is not going to implode based on the addition of the column and populating it with data. I would prefer to do it in a way that utilizes one of the native SP functions/pages and I can live with the potential for migration troubles in the future. I don't mean to sound like I'm dismissing your advice because I think it is very sound, I just don't have the ability to attempt to implement one of those solutions at this time.

Comment: I actually more a matter of configuration rather than implementation, you don't really have to touch code, except for xml configuratiin via .config files.